# Android Studio + NDK: C++ Editor does not work

Tags: c++, android-ndk, inspect, android-studio-2.0

I am using Android studio 2.0 on Window with NDK.
I can build and run project successfully but C++ editor does not work.
It cannot find includes file, so also cannot suggest API.
On Eclipse, we can easily add include path, but not Android Studio.

Will we have to continue waiting Google to update new feature?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is supported from Android Studio 2.2 onwards